# Java, protected access of methods of nested subclass not working. Forced to public

Tags: java

```
public abstract class SuperClass<T> {

        public Nested nested = new Nested(); // This might still be a case where the public have access to an instance. 

        protected SuperClass() {
                create(null);
        }

        protected abstract void create(T t);
        protected void test(T t) {

        }

        protected class Nested {
               protected void method() {

               }
        }

}

// For this example this class should be in a different package
public class ExtendsSuperClass extends SuperClass<Void> {

        @Override
        protected void create(Void v) {
                super.test(v);         // Works fine
                nested.method();       // Does not when outside of the same package. protected must then become public.
        }
}
```

If ExtendsSuperclass is in a different package you are now forced to expose the create method **as a public one.**

SuperClass can have a instance of Nested that is exposed to the public while still having the need to control which methods a subclass can access and what the public cant.

Now its not possible. The SuperClass can access private and protected methods, and if you choose to leave an extendor extend the SuperClass to have similar privileges as it self you can't without exposing access.

**Does this not constitute as a bug?**

In the same package this does not pose a problem. Protected works ( or actually it's package private then )

Comment: if method() is protected, then you cannot access it... you can only access it if you are extending the class...

Comment: @Sotirios this is not a duplicate. The class of Nested is not a static member of SuperClass. In fact, it is part of the SuperClass and Subclass instance. Everything in the superclass is visible to the Nested class. Protected should apply here. I would recommend that this is reopened so it can be further discussed and a proper answer to why this is the case here.

Comment: @FrEaKmAn By extending Superclass protected should apply to Nested as well. You can't infact even do new Nested() from the subclass, even though that class is protected, so it is not even visible from there. Even though the class is marked as protected ( not members of that class )

Comment: The question then becomes what is the purpose of allowing protected on a nested class when it is really only package private.

Comment: The accepted answer states _A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object._ In your case, `ExtendsSuperClass` is not responsible for the implementation of `Nested#method` and therefore cannot access it (if it's in a different package).

Comment: Similarly, in `ExtendsSuperClass`, you could not have something like `SuperClass<Void> sc = null; sc.test(null);` because `ExtendsSuperClass` is not responsible for that implementation, `SuperClass` is.

Comment: Ok, I give you an upvote but I still think this sucks

Comment: hm, feel free to create a new language to support this :) they are popular these days...